# Getting TypeError: "path" is not defined: undefined while executing serial port program for windows using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arduino, serial-port

I am trying to execute a Serial Port program for windows based application using JavaScript and Arduino Uno. This is the link i referred https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/raw-tech/Arduino-talks-back-to-Nodejs-Drama-on-the-Serial-Port. While i try to execute the program by issuing npm start COMxx. Iam getting the following error.

```
App threw an error during load
TypeError: "path" is not defined: undefined
    at new SerialPort (C:\serial test js\serial-app\node_modules\@serialport\stream\lib\index.js:116:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\serial test js\serial-app\src\index.js:7:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1078:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1108:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:935:32)
    at Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:14)
    at Function.f._load (electron/js2c/asar_bundle.js:5:12684)
    at loadApplicationPackage (C:\serial test js\serial-app\node_modules\electron\dist\resources\default_app.asar\main.js:110:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\serial test js\serial-app\node_modules\electron\dist\resources\default_app.asar\main.js:222:9)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1078:30)
```

And this is my code

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron');
const path = require('path');
const SerialPort = require('serialport');
const Readline = SerialPort.parsers.Readline;
const portname = process.argv[2];

const myPort = new SerialPort(portname, {
  baudRate:9600,
  parser: new Readline("\n")
});

myPort.on('open',onOpen);
myPort.on('data',onData);

// Handle creating/removing shortcuts on Windows when installing/uninstalling.
if (require('electron-squirrel-startup')) { // eslint-disable-line global-require
  app.quit();
}

const createWindow = () => {
  // Create the browser window.
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
  });

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  mainWindow.loadFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'));

  // Open the DevTools.
  mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
};

function onOpen(){
  console.log("Open Connection");
}

function onData(data){
  console.log("on Data "+data);


}
// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.on('ready', createWindow);

// Quit when all windows are closed, except on macOS. There, it's common
// for applications and their menu bar to stay active until the user quits
// explicitly with Cmd + Q.
app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit();
  }
});

app.on('activate', () => {
  // On OS X it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
  // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
  if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
    createWindow();
  }
});

// In this file you can include the rest of your app's specific main process
// code. You can also put them in separate files and import them here.
```

Help me to resolve the issue

Answer (score 6):

Instead :

```
const myPort = new SerialPort(portname, {
  baudRate:9600,
  parser: new Readline("\n")
});
```

Try this :

```
const myPort = new SerialPort({
  path:portname,
  baudRate:9600,
  parser: new Readline("\n")
});
```

Answer (score 2):

As per the new version of serialport this code syntax is not working

This program will not work

```
const myPort = new SerialPort(portname, {
  baudRate:9600,
  parser: new Readline("\n")
});
```

Just add the portname like this

```
const myPort = new SerialPort({
      path: portname
      baudRate:9600,
      parser: new Readline("\n")
    });
```

This is worked for me

Comment: This is why, we should not give up on StackOverflow.

Answer (score -3):

As path is a part of nodejs core module, it doesn't need to be listed explicitly

```
const path = require('path');
```

Just try to stop your solution and re-run application it should be working.

Comment: Even after i commented the line const path = require('path'); and run the app i am getting the same error.