# SerialPort saying Path Not Found

Tags: node.js, serial-port

When I try and create a new Serial port, I get an error saying

```
/home/gabriel/projects/arduiscordbot/node_modules/@serialport/stream/dist/index.js:50
            throw new TypeError(`"path" is not defined: ${settings.path}`);
            ^

TypeError: "path" is not defined: undefined
```

My code is simply

```js
const { SerialPort }= require('serialport')
const Readline = require('@serialport/parser-readline');

const port = new SerialPort('/dev/ttyACM0', { baudRate: 9600 });
port.write('hello from node\n', (err) => {
    if (err) {
      return console.log('Error on write: ', err.message);
    }
    console.log('msg written')
});
```

I have tried playing around with the placement of various bits inside of the new SerialPort array, however I either get this error or something saying SerialPort is not a constructor. I know that the port I used exists.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting TypeError: "path" is not defined: undefined while executing serial port program for windows using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67460624/getting-typeerror-path-is-not-defined-undefined-while-executing-serial-port)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've updated from `serialport@9.x` to `serialport@10.x`+ there was a breaking change to the API as documented [here](https://serialport.io/docs/guide-upgrade#constructor).  `path` now needs to be specified as part of the [OpenOptions](https://serialport.io/docs/api-stream#openoptions):

```
const port = new SerialPort({ path: '/dev/ttyACM0', baudRate: 9600 });
```

Comment: Bro I asked this question like 6 months ago why are you here

Comment: To help others who, like me, got to this page while looking for a solution to the same issue